# get shipping price outside Magento

Tags: magento

I'm trying to create an order outside Magento, my current problem is that I need to know the shipping tablerate cost before creating the order in Magento.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Table rates are stored in `shipping_tablerate` table. So knowing your calculation type (Magento table rates have 3 calculation variants) and order conditions (weight, price, destination, # of items) query database directly.
2. You can create a quote object, add quote items and addresses and then run `Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping::collectRatesByAddress`.